# Arabic text Editor for website like WYSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, text-editor, arabic

Is there any open source text editor like ckeditor that we can embed into our website for arabic input?

Answer (score 0):

[Google Virtual Keyboard](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Keyboard)?

see also this sample: http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/closureeditortransliteration.html

Answer (score 0):

There appears that ckeditor has Arabic support based on their demo page

http://ckeditor.com/demo

Are you wanting something that allows users who have English keyboards to type Arabic characters?